# Como impedir que o numero seja menor ou igual a 0 num input type number?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Boa noite.
Eu tenho um input type number (para quando listo o meu carrinho de compras poder alterar a quantidade)

```
<td>
   <input 
       type="number" 
       style="width: 50px;"
       id="<?php echo "p" . $a; ?>"
       min="1"
       max="<?php echo $max_produto; ?>"
       value="<?php echo $values["item_quantity"]; ?>"
   >
</td>
```

O meu problema é que mesmo definindo o min e o max, se eu alterar diretamente no input sem utilizar as setas posso por o valor 0, ou inferior a 0, que quando confirmo a compra ele fica com a quantidade posta e não deveria acontecer.
Como posso resolver este problema?

Comment: Só utilizando o `required` e `min=1` aqui funcionou: http://jsbin.com/pocilifana. Como está submetendo o formulário?

Comment: Você pretende fazer a verificação apenas no client ou no server? A questão ficou ambígua.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre no client

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss tentei e não resultou :(

Comment: @TiagoSimoes acredito que a resposta do Valdeir seja a solução, se for o caso, seria melhor você confirmar, ao invés de continuar com os comentários.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre já testei e não funcionou, e aliás não sei pq o meu comentário à solução do colega não foi enviado :S

Comment: <input type="number" ..... oninput="if(this.value == 0) this.value = ''" />

Comment: `<input type="number" ...... oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)"/>`

Answer (score 2):

Existem várias formas, uma delas é verificar a propriedade `validity.valid`. Será verdadeiro se e somente se a entrada estiver dentro do intervalo.

```html
<input 
       type="number" 
       style="width: 50px;"
       id="qqid"
       min="1"
       max="11"
       value="" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" />
```

> O único problema com a solução acima é que ela limpa completamente o valor inserido anteriormente quando um valor inválido é inserido.

**Isso pode ser evitado da seguinte forma:**

```html
<input 
       type="number" 
       style="width: 50px;"
       id="qqid"
       min="1"
       max="11"
       value="" oninput="validity.valid ? this.save = value : value = this.save;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta você utilizar o evento `input` através do *JavaScript*.

**Segue código e explicação:**

```js
/* O evento input do DOM é disparado sincronicamente quando o valor de um elemento <input>, <select>, ou <textarea> é alterado. */
document.querySelector("#qualquer-coisa").addEventListener("input", el => {
 
  /* Verifica se o valor alterado é maior que o valor do atributo max */
 if (el.target.value > parseInt(el.target.getAttribute("max"))) {
  
   /* Caso seja, define o valor do atributo max */
   el.target.value = el.target.getAttribute("max");
  }
  
  /* Verifica se o valor alterado é menor que 0 */
 if (el.target.value <= parseInt(el.target.getAttribute("min"))) {
  
   /* Caso seja, define o valor 0 */
   el.target.value = 1;
  }
})
```

```html
<input 
       type="number" 
       style="width: 50px;"
       id="qualquer-coisa"
       min="1"
       max="11"
       value="8" />
```

> **Obs:** Além do evento `input`, você pode optar por: `paste` ou `change`

Comment: Não está evitando valor 0 (zero). A pergunta é: Como IMPEDIR que o numero seja menor ou IGUAL a 0 num input type number?  Resposta correta seria com `el.target.value = "";`